# How to filter a dataset using Select and a parameter

Tags: dataset

I'd like to filter a `Dataset` using a parameter in `Select`, but so far I haven't been able to make it work properly. Say that I have the following data:

```
data = {
   {"Group", "aa", "bb"}
   , {"A", 3.24, 9.68}
   , {"B", 3.5, "-"}
   , {"C", "", 6.79}
   };
```

I convert my data to a dataset:

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[First@data, #] & /@ Rest@data]
```

Extracting only these datasets, in which the aa data are numbers:

```
dataset[Select[NumberQ[#"aa"] &]]
```

Now I want to either select aa or bb using a parameter, but why doesn't this work?

```
sel = "aa"
dataset[Select[NumberQ[#sel] &]]
```

Comment: Possible dupe.  This is covered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59732/select-data-from-a-dataset?rq=1

Comment: basically Select[#State =="New York" || #Population > 2000000 &]@cityDS  (or cityAssoc)  for a Dataset you can also use DS[Select[#State=="New York" &],"Population"]  selecting the "Population" column of the dataset DS where the "State" column = New York.  Use || for OR and && for AND logical operators

Comment: `dataset[Select[NumberQ[#[sel]] &]]` or `dataset[Select[NumberQ[#@sel] &]]` . Read the scope section of the [#(Slot) docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks (again!). I did read through the #-Sektion, but couldn't get it to work. I'll certainly go through the Scope section again. – My program is finished now. Dataset is somewhat tricky to get your (i.e. my ...) head around. But it seems quite powerful once you get it.

Comment: @Gordon Coale, I went through the topic you identified as possible dupe, but didn't find the answer there. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @SquareOne - probably worth posting as an answer as the 2nd #@sel format isn't on the Slot help page.

Comment: @GordonCoale Actually you can use this shorthand for every function : `f[x]` can also be written `f@x`. Here `f` is `Slot` or `#`. But I agree it is rather unusual to see `#@sel` and it is useful so then maybe it is worth posting ;)

Comment: @SquareOne thank you, that clarified the magic of the notation there and solved a problem I've been trying to track down for hours now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example does not work because `#sel` is a special shorthand notation that is interpreted as if we had written `#["sel"]`.  Observe that *sel* becomes quoted as part of the expansion, meaning that the expression will attempt to select the (non-existent) value associated with the literal string `"sel"`.  This shorthand is mentioned in the *Details* section of the [documentation for Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html).

To make the example work, we need to explicitly specify `sel` in unquoted form so that it will be evaluated.  `#[sel]` is what we need:

```
sel = "aa";
dataset[Select[NumberQ[#[sel]] &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Alternatively, we could use the part notation `#[[sel]]`:

```
dataset[Select[NumberQ[#[[sel]]] &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Such notation is listed in the [documentation for Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

**Update**

As noted by commentators, there is nothing special about the expression `#[sel]` that would prevent us from using prefix form (`# @ sel`) or postfix form (`sel // #`) if desired.

Comment: worth adding squareones second example as a third way or doing it?

Comment: @GordonCoale Done.